# Choice of tape for Kraft-faced insulation

Tags: drywall, insulation, vapor-barrier, tape

I am preparing my home remodel for a HERS (Home Energy Rating System) insulation inspection. The design included a typical amount of over-engineering for new construction in California (Bay Area), and this has meant that there are a lot of hold-downs, and other kinds of thermal bridging. And it has meant that almost no stud bays are on layout. So most of the kraft-faced insulation has been cut to fit the irregular widths. As a result the job just doesn't look very clean, and as an owner-builder I am concerned with making sure the job looks clean and professional.

I know this is probably technically unnecessary, but I am wondering if there is a kind of vapor barrier tape that I can use to clean up all of the loose edges of the Kraft paper that have been cut to fit the irregular stud bays. Is this something that professional insulations crews do?

Comment: I don't have a good answer, but in my experience kraft paper is difficult to stick to. You definitely need a purpose-built product or it'll just let go in fairly short order. I would want any joints not lapping to be taped.

Comment: It sounds like a lot of tape to be used.  Just wondering if it would not be better to slice the paper and use 4 or 6mm plastic vapour barrier over everything.  It usually seals against air drafts/leaks much better since there are no open seams.  Will depend on California rules/regulations.

Comment: @crip659 kind of what I was thinking the poster should do. Use unfaced and then a separate vapor barrier.

Comment: The job is 80% complete, so unfaced isn't really an option. I was just looking for a way to clean up what I've already done.